# Code: Authorization_RequestDenied Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: .net, microsoft-graph-api

I have an Azure Function app that adds and removes users to specific group in Azure AD.

The add code works but when I try to call:

```
await GraphHelper.graphClient.Groups[groupId].Members[userToRemove.Id].Request().DeleteAsync();
```

I get error:

```
Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

When I check the App Registration used I see that the following permissions are set:

- Directory.Read.All
- Directory.ReadWrite.All
- Group.Read.All
- Group.ReadWrite.All
- GroupMember.Read.All
- GroupMember.ReadWrite.All

What am I missing?

**Update**
The following code add user to a group does work

```
await GraphHelper.graphClient.Groups[groupId].Members.References.Request().AddAsync(userToAdd);
```

Comment: How are you creating the token? Are you missing the 'Referece' key word as specified in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-delete-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request)?

Comment: Have you given the Admin concent to App in AAD?

Comment: Yes I have admin consent. Also adding user to a group works. Just removing fails.

Comment: Please add this permission RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory. See the Important Note [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-delete-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#permissions)

Comment: I added that permission, but unfortunately, same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating and searching more, due to information added by Shiva Keshav Varma, I found the issue.

I needed to add 'RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory' as Api permission and change the code.

The code should be:

await GraphHelper.graphClient.Groups[groupId].Members[userToRemove.Id].**Reference**.Request().DeleteAsync()

I needed to add **Reference** to the request. I found the answer here [Micrsoft documentation](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/main/api-reference/beta/includes/snippets/csharp/delete-member-from-group-csharp-snippets.md)

Comment: Glad to here that it worked for you :)